Kafka message compression not working (broker level)
I added compression for log messages on broker level compression.type=zstd on all three brokers with no other changes on the broker level or producer level.
When I tried to read messages from my python client (Consumer) for kafka, I started getting timeouts. Consumer didn't respond with any messages from that point. I reverted this change on all three brokers and now I can access messages again.
Where did I go wrong and how can I enable compression on the message logs correctly? Should I add compression on Producer level now as well? Thanks in advance.

After few hours of debugging the error, it turns out there is a problem only when using Zstd compression via Python for Kafka consumers. Gzip works just fine for compressing messages using Broker.
